# Using AWK command I need to replace the column values for particular columns which is having 0000000X

Tags: text-processing, awk

I need to replace a column value in a fixed width file which is having unknown value in one of the columns and need to replace the column value with some column value in the same line.

```
      A      B      C      D        E    F      G     H     I     J      K     L      M      N
ex: 123908 456567 675674 0000000x 45678 09756 125678 45678 09756 125678 45678 09756 125678 45678 09756
```

here instead of `0000000x` (column D), I need to replace it with `125678` (column G).

I have tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{f=0;for(i=292;i<=300;i++){if($i!~/0000000X/){f=1}};if(f) {for(i=292;i<=300;i++){$i=2}};print }'
```

This command  is changing for the respective column in all rows. But I need to be changed for the particular column having the `0000000x` value.

Comment: Why not change the column the very moment you identify it (i.e. in the first `for` loop)? You don't use the G column in your one liner. How do you determine the `G` column?

Comment: Do you need to replace `0000000x` because it has that value in column D or do you need to change whatever value is in column D? Setting `FS=""` is undefined behavior so it'll do different things in different awks but none of them will do anything you want to do. You say your input is fixed width fields but then you show input that has space-separated fields and you don't tell us the start char pos and length of "column D" or "column G" if the input really is fixed width so it's hard to know how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Given this input:

```
$ cat file
a X c D e X f
a B c D e X f
```

It sounds like you're trying to do either this:

```
$ awk '$2=="X"{$2=$4} 1' file
a D c D e X f
a B c D e X f
```

or this:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="X") $i=$4} 1' file
a D c D e D f
a B c D e D f
```

If it's neither of those then please edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide a more truly representative example.